# Rewrite Api - Invalid Api Path

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, api, soap

i'm new with magento, but i need help with API rewrite.
I've added some methods up to Catalog_Product_Api_V2 which are working well.
I can also call them with SOAPv2.
Now i want to add product attributes product "catalogProductAttributeCreate(...)" but now  i'm getting this error message: 
*Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [3] Invalid api path. ...*

Here's my SOAPv2 Call:

```
$data = array(
    "attribute_code" => "test_attribute",
    "frontend_input" => "text",
    "scope" => "1",
    "default_value" => "1",
    "is_unique" => 0,
    "is_required" => 0,
    "apply_to" => array("simple"),
    "is_configurable" => 0,
    "is_searchable" => 0,
    "is_visible_in_advanced_search" => 0,
    "is_comparable" => 0,
    "is_used_for_promo_rules" => 0,
    "is_visible_on_front" => 0,
    "used_in_product_listing" => 0,
    "additional_fields" => array(),
    "frontend_label" => array(array("store_id" => "0", "label" => "some label"))
   );

   $result10 = $client->catalogProductAttributeCreate($session, $data);
```

Here's my **config.xml**

```
<catalog>
    <rewrite>
        <product_api_v2>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Catalog_Product_Api_V2</product_api_v2>
    </rewrite>
</catalog>
```

Do I overwrite all the standard methods like "create, update, info, etc."?
Please help me... :)